# Hera: Replace files with Nautilus

Tags: pantheon-files, nautilus

Files has no way to search with in a directory while Nautilus does.
How to I replace Files with Nautilus?

Answer (score 2):

Files does have a search facility - you just start typing or press `<Ctrl>F` and type into the pathbar (which doubles as search entry).  The first results returned are those found in the current directory.  It also returns (grouped separately) results found in subfolders of the current folder, in bookmarks and in recently used.

However, if you wish you can install Nautilus from the AppCenter.

Comment: I have Nautilus installed.I just want to use it as the default file manager. Like if I try to upload a picture to Facebook from chrome, is seem like it goes to Files instead of Nautilus. I would that to be Nautilus.

Comment: You can set the default file browser with System Settings/Applications/Defaults

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that setting Nautilus as the default file manager works correctly.
For example, I'm using chrome as a browser, and after choosing **Downloads** from the menu, and open the folder for a particular downloaded file, ElementaryOS open **Pantheon Files** instead of Nautilus